# nodejs buffers vs typed arrays

Tags: node.js

What is more efficient - nodejs buffers or typed arrays? What should I use for better performance?
I think that only those who know interiors of V8 and NodeJs could answer this question.

Answer (score 7):

A Node.js `buffer` should be more efficient than a typed array. The reason is simply because when a new Node.js Buffer is created it does not need to be initialized to all 0's. Whereas, the HTML5 spec states that initialization of typed arrays must have their values set to 0. Allocating the memory and then setting all of the memory to 0's takes more time.

In most applications picking either one won't matter. As always, the devil lies in the benchmarks :) However, I recommend that you pick one and stick with it. If you're often converting back and forth between the two, you'll take a performance hit.

Nice discussion here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4884

Comment: It seems like [Node 8](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_size) has deprecated this "feature" for security reasons.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things that I think are worth mentioning:

1. `Buffer` instances are [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) instances but there are subtle incompatibilities with the TypedArray specification in ECMAScript 2015. For example, while `ArrayBuffer#slice()` creates a copy of the slice, the implementation of `Buffer#slice()` creates a view over the existing Buffer without copying, making `Buffer#slice()` far more efficient.
2. When using `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` and `Buffer.allocUnsafeSlow()` the memory isn't zeroed-out (as many have pointed out already). So make sure you completely overwrite the allocated memory or you can allow the old data to be leaked when the Buffer memory is read.
3. `TypedArrays` are not readable right away, you'll need a `DataView` for that. Which means you might need to rewrite your code if you were to migrate back to `Buffer`. [Adapter pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/adapter-design-pattern) could help here.
4. You can use [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) on `Buffer`. You cannot on `TypedArrays`. Also you won't have the classic `entries()`, `values()`, `keys()` and `length` support.
5. `Buffer` is not supported in the frontend while `TypedArray` may well be. So if your code is shared between frontend or backend you might consider sticking to one.

[More info in the docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray).

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one, but I think that it will depend on what are you planning to do with them and how much data you are planning to work with?

typed arrays themselves need node buffers, but are easier to play with and you can overcome the 1GB limit (kMaxLength = 0x3fffffff).

If you are doing common stuff such as iterations, setting, getting, slicing, etc... then typed arrays should be your best shot for performance, not memory ( specially if you are dealing with float and 64bits integer types ).

In the end, probably only a good benchmark with what you want to do can shed real light on this doubt.